# Testing an Rspec Controller with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, controller

I've got two models:

```
class Solution < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates_attachment_presence :software
  validates_presence_of :price, :language, :title
  validates_uniqueness_of :software_file_name, :scope => :user_id

  has_attached_file :software
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :primary_phone_number
  validates_uniqueness_of :primary_phone_number

  has_many :solutions
end
```

with my routes looking like this:

```
map.resources :user, :has_many => :solutions
```

Now I'm trying to test my solutions controllers with the following RSpec test:

```
describe SolutionsController do

  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory.build(:user)
    @solution = Factory.build(:solution, :user => @user)
  end

 describe "GET index" do
   it "should find all of the solutions owned by a user" do
     Solution.should_receive(:find_by_user_id).with(@user.id).and_return(@solutions)
     get :index, :id => @user.id
   end
 end
end
```

However, this gets me the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError in 'SolutionsController GET index should find all of the solutions owned by a user'
No route matches {:id=>nil, :controller=>"solutions", :action=>"index"}
```

Can anybody point me to how I can test this, since the index should always be called within the scope of a particular user?

Answer (score 4):

`Factory#build` builds an instance of the class, but doesn't save it, so it doesn't have an id yet.

So, `@user.id` is nil because `@user` has not been saved.

Because `@user.id` is nil, your route isn't activated.

try using `Factory#create` instead.

```
  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory.create(:user)
    @solution = Factory.create(:solution, :user => @user)
  end
```

Comment: Ok, that got my closer, but now I just get:
    ActionController::RoutingError in 'SolutionsController GET index should find all of the solutions owned by a user'
    No route matches {:id=>848, :controller=>"solutions", action=>"index"}

Comment: chrisdinn's answer has the solution for that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your other problem is on this line:

```
 get :index, :id => @user.id
```

You're trying to make a request to the index method, but you've provided the wrong variable name. When testing `SolutionsController` `id` implies a solution id, you need to supply the user id. This should work, or at least move you forward:

```
 get :index, :user_id => @user.id
```